# len function TypeError: 'int' object is not callable Is jupyter alright?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook and trying to run this code but always getting this error. Is there something wrong with my code or with the Jupyter Notebook.

```
length = 0
for item in df['documents']:
    newL = len(item)
    if newL>length:
        length=newL
print(length)
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: please provide more context, such as version number, environment, stack trace, etc.

Comment: Remove extra spaces

Comment: Somewhere you have assigned an integer to the name `len`.

Comment: Somewhere earlier in your session you did something like `len = 0`. So you don't have the built-in function `len()` anymore. Do `print(len)` to see this. Restart your interpreter to get rid of past mistakes.

Comment: @BoarGules I havent done anything like this.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski no such assignment was made

Comment: @Sabesh the error is: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: In a previous comment I asked you to do `print(len)`. Have you done that, and if so what was the result? If not please do it now. The result should be `<built-in function len>`. If it is a number then you have accidentally redefined `len()`. If you get `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` then you have accidentally redefined `print()`.